# How can I partially clear my terminal scrollback?

Tags: terminal, iterm2, iterm

I want to partially clear my terminal scrollback history, but only from where I have selected with my mouse in the scrollback and up. Is this possible? I'm on a Mac, and I use iTerm2 and Terminal.

Comment: `bash` doesn't have any notion of scrollback; that's something your terminal emulator manages.

Comment: @chepner - ok, good point. I just reframed the question to not be about bash.

Comment: Landed here from a search for fully clearing scrollback. If you need to fully clear scrollback, `right-click` -> `clear buffer`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Not sure about partially, but you can fully clear your scrollback with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will only clear the screen, not the scrollback content/history/buffer.

If you want the partial scrollback badly enough, [this](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/97893deb8fe2e12741f589f5daf6bff320ca4649/VT100Terminal.m#L3940-L3941) would probably be the place to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, but man, that is some nasty code! I don't think I'd ever want anything so badly that I would have to get in to that codebase. :-)

Comment: If this is still true - and it seems it is - that's very disappointing. The scrollback buffer looks like a trash dump, picking up bits from the pager & randomly over-writing stuff that might actually be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but you can clear just the screen by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-clear-the-terminal-command-history/

This will clear the history completely. history -c

No way I could find to do a partial.

Answer (score -2):

This command will most probably give you the possible history files. You can open it in a text editor and edit.

```
ls -a ~ | grep hist
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please reread the question- OP is asking about scrollback, not history.

Answer (score -4):

If I have correctly understood your question, I think that you can achieve that by manually editing your history file, `~/.bash_history`.

P.S.: In order to save your current session, you have to first close the Terminal.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood. The .bash_history file is for the command history, not the terminal scrollback history.