# Scrolling up in iTerm2 shows previous Vim sessions

Tags: macos, terminal, scrolling, iterm2

In iTerm2 (Version 2.1.4), when I scroll up to see previous commands, I'm seeing chunks of previous Vim sessions, which I don't want to see. Any idea why that would be happening and how to fix that?

As an example, here's some output after I typed a line of a file in Vim, then scrolled up. The top line is a remnant of the Vim session. (I have line numbers on in Vim, which is where the `1` comes from.)

```
  1 I'm typing a line in Vim.
Last login: Tue Jan  5 10:16:18 on ttys001
imac:~$ vi test.txt
imac:~$ cat test.txt
I'm typing a line in Vim.
imac:~$
```

Sometimes much larger remnants are displayed. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I partially clear my terminal scrollback?](http://superuser.com/questions/576410/how-can-i-partially-clear-my-terminal-scrollback)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with clearing scrollback. I want my scrollback history available, but I don't want it interspersed with lines from Vim sessions when I scroll up. In the small example I placed above, the line starting with `Last login:` should be the top of the session. Nothing should show up above it if I try to scroll up, but what's showing up there is a remnant from a Vim session that shouldn't show up there, and doesn't show up if I'm in Terminal.app instead of iTerm2.

Comment: @BenLindsay, any resolution to this? I see the same happening in my terminal on Mac.

Comment: @Jens Yes, George Nachman resolved my problem a long time ago. I posted an answer. Hope that helps! If you're seeing that on Terminal.app then I can't help you, but this should fix it on iTerm2!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[George Nachman](https://gitlab.com/gnachman), the iTerm2 guy, ended up solving my problem [here](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/5136). In short, I just needed to uncheck **Prefs > Profiles > Terminal > Save lines to scrollback in alternate screen mode** in the iTerm2 menu.

Comment: Thank you. I’m using [rxvt](http://rxvt.sourceforge.net/) on [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) and was hoping for a hint I’ll dig around, but it looks like the terminal itself is the culprit which needs massaging?

Comment: Doesn't work for me using iTerm2@3.4.15. I must have another setting checked..

Answer (score 0):

I’m running [urxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) in [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) and had the same problem. What fixed it for me was to add the following to `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
urxvt*secondaryScreen: 1
urxvt*secondaryScroll: 0
```

From the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt):

> **secondaryScreen**: boolean
>   Turn on/off secondary screen (default enabled).
>   **secondaryScroll**: boolean
>   Turn on/off secondary screen scroll (default enabled). If this option is enabled, scrolls on the secondary screen will change the scrollback buffer and, when secondaryScreen is off, switching to/from the secondary screen will instead scroll the screen up.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is having a problem getting Ben Lindsay's solution to work, make sure that the profile selected is the current one you are using; it's not always the case when you open your prferences - it's the one with the star next to it:

[image]